# How to @import an alternative stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to @import an alternative stylesheet from a CSS but how do I declare it alternative without making a seperate line in my html importing it manually?

Currently I have

### main.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s1.css" title="standard">
```

### s1.css

```
@import "s2.css"; <--- the stylesheet I want to be alternative
body{
background-color: gray;
}
```

### s2.css <-- stylesheet I want alternative

```
@import "s3.css" print;
div{
color: red;
}
```

### s3.css <-- stylesheet for print

```
h1{
color: green;
}
```

Is there some keyword for alternative stylesheet? all I found so far are

screen, for presentation on non-paged computer screens;

print, for output to a printer;

projection, for projected presentations;

aural, for speech synthesizers;

braille, for presentation on braille tactile feedback devices;

tty, for character cell displays (using a fixed-pitch font);

tv, for televisions;

all, for all output devices.

Comment: what do you mean for "alternative"?

Comment: equivalent of link rel="alternate stylesheet"

Comment: good to know, is it still being used now days? just tried https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/altstyles/index.html i can see nothing under that menu, firefox here.

Comment: It works (http://i.imgur.com/MvbZjDr.png) however I think they were imported by adding the link in the .html instead of `@import` from a css. I want to use `@import` via css for the alternative stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah they did. If you inspect you'll see this in the html: `<link href="insane.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Insane">`

Comment: i mean i don't see the options via View>Page Style submenu on firefox, you should make sure whether that still works on all major browsers.

Comment: It's a question on how to do it for educational purposes not for an actual website.

Answer (score 0):

`@import` does not support specifying `alternate` as it is designed to specify a dependency of the stylesheet it appears in.

So you have to declare all alternatives in HTML.  If the alternatives have common parts, you can put it into a separate stylesheet and import that into the alternatives.

When an alternative stylesheet is chosen, all the others are ignored, so declaring alternatives in a stylesheet would have no effect even if it was possible.